# How to share parts of a string with Rc?

Tags: string, rust, slice, reference-counting

I want to create some references to a `str` with `Rc`, without cloning `str`:

```
fn main() {
    let s = Rc::<str>::from("foo");
    let t = Rc::clone(&s); // Creating a new pointer to the same address is easy
    let u = Rc::clone(&s[1..2]); // But how can I create a new pointer to a part of `s`?

    let w = Rc::<str>::from(&s[0..2]); // This seems to clone str
    assert_ne!(&w as *const _, &s as *const _);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c9d7278ceab479a5efd98c1203d9e696)

How can I do this?

Comment: this obviously can't work with `Rc`. I would encapsulate the Rc with a struct that handle the substr I guess

Comment: Thanks, why do I should encapsulate it?

Answer (score 6):

While it's possible in principle, the standard library's `Rc` does not support the case you're trying to create: a counted reference to a *part* of reference-counted memory.

However, we can get the effect for strings using a fairly straightforward wrapper around `Rc` which remembers the substring range:

```
use std::ops::{Deref, Range};
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
pub struct RcSubstr {
    string: Rc<str>,
    span: Range<usize>,
}

impl RcSubstr {
    fn new(string: Rc<str>) -> Self {
        let span = 0..string.len();
        Self { string, span }
    }
    fn substr(&self, span: Range<usize>) -> Self {
        // A full implementation would also have bounds checks to ensure
        // the requested range is not larger than the current substring
        Self {
            string: Rc::clone(&self.string),
            span: (self.span.start + span.start)..(self.span.start + span.end)
        }
    }
}

impl Deref for RcSubstr {
    type Target = str;
    fn deref(&self) -> &str {
        &self.string[self.span.clone()]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = RcSubstr::new(Rc::<str>::from("foo"));
    let u = s.substr(1..2);
    
    // We need to deref to print the string rather than the wrapper struct.
    // A full implementation would `impl Debug` and `impl Display` to produce
    // the expected substring.
    println!("{}", &*u);
}
```

There are a lot of conveniences missing here, such as suitable implementations of `Display`, `Debug`, `AsRef`, `Borrow`, `From`, and `Into` — I've provided only enough code to illustrate how it *can work.* Once supplemented with the appropriate trait implementations, this should be just as usable as `Rc<str>` (with the one edge case that it can't be passed to a library type that wants to store `Rc<str>` *in particular*).

The crate [`arcstr`](https://crates.io/crates/arcstr) claims to offer a finished version of this basic idea, but I haven't used or studied it and so can't guarantee its quality.

The crate [`owning_ref`](https://crates.io/crates/owning_ref) provides a way to hold references to parts of an Rc or other smart pointer, but there are concerns about its soundness and I don't fully understand which circumstances that applies to ([issue search](https://github.com/Kimundi/owning-ref-rs/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+unsound) which currently has 3 open issues).

Comment: @eggyal Here's the [open issues mentioning 'unsound'](https://github.com/Kimundi/owning-ref-rs/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+unsound). From a quick scan, it looks like they might all not apply to this type of usage, but as I said, I don't fully understand the scope and I don't feel comfortable mention using `owning_ref` *without* also mentioning the caveat. Thanks for prompting me to make it more specific than FUD though!

Comment: Great code, you beat me to the punch by several minutes, and provided a slightly nicer impl to boot. The only thing I'd add is `as_str(&self) -> &str { &* self }` because I find the `&*x` idiom very unintuitive and evocative of Perl-style symbol soups (but maybe that's just me).

Comment: @user4815162342 This is only intended as an illustration of the principle, not adequate code to use — there's lots of conversions and traits that would be useful or almost necessary. I've added a disclaimer about that.

Comment: @eggyal Thanks! Is it possible for `BTreeSet` to have this `RcSubstr` if necessary trait (Ord) is implemented?

Comment: @KevinReid Sure, it was just a suggestion, feel free to ignore it if you don't agree. As i said, I actually like the your answer as is and I wouldn't add all that much to it (except the aforementioned `as_str()`).